# How to create an expandable row in gwt

Tags: gwt, row, expandable

[image]

As seen on the right, I want to create an expandable row. I am confused how to use TableCellBuilder and/or buildContactRow.

Could someone give me any pointers or point me to a tutorial

I am thinking of using a disclosure panel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Disclosure panel(perfomance is good). 
In my project i have tried TableCellBuilder with cell table but not works what i expected.

Using Disclosure panel you can enable animation also. I have created more that 300 Disclosure panel at a single hit dynamically data from mysql db. but it works fine. so perfomance and efficient is faster in UI.

Comment: Perfect, the efficiency is what I was looking for